# remove disks or other media during installation

Tags: system-installation, laptop

im trying to install 12.04 on my lenovo T60 via a usb stick.
 I downloaded the latest iso, loaded it on the usb stick after i formatted it and now im trying to boot from it to start the installer.

After changing the boot priority to boot off usb-hdd i get the message `remove disks or other media /n Press any key to restart`

Ive checked my startup boot menu and removed everything except for the  usb-hdd and I still get this message. I still have Windows installed on the hard drive and was planning on formatting it during the installation-  I'm not sure maybe this is getting in the way.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out - I needed to create a bootable disk which I did using [this guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

dropping the iso into a formatted usb drive simply wasnt enough.

Comment: lol that's what I did the first time I tried to prepare a Linux CD also, just burned the ISO as a file to the CD instead of burning it as an image