# Installation problem - missing boot manager

Tags: system-installation

While trying to install from a USB stick, I get the message (from BIOS I think):
"BOOTMGR is missing" and the computer hangs.

On my C drive is a corrupt version of Win 7 which I cannot repair or remove. Hence, having had enough of Microsoft, I would like to try Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Change boot device to USB from bios menu

Comment: Changing boot device to USB from bios menu did not work, but this worked https://askubuntu.com/a/350075/466989

Answer (score 0):

You need to access your **BIO's** most machines use **F-2** and change the boot order in order to boot up from the USB drive. Then when you start up your machine hit **F-12** and choose the USB drive and proceed with your installation